# .htaccess RewriteRule not working correctly, site only works with www

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, dns

A website I am working on works fine when you visit www.sandicliffe.co.uk but sandicliffe.co.uk does not.

The DNS is set up correctly, as it reaches my .htaccess file but it is here it seems to fail. There is an A record to the site and a record for www as well.

Running a ping on both with and without www. works fine.

We have the following lines in the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sandicliffe\.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.sandicliffe.co.uk/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
RewriteRule    ^$    public/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) public/$1    [L]
```

The site routes through a front controller in the public directory.

Having done more research, I have found the following:

My machine in Chrome Stable and Beta and Canary, does not load.
My machine in Firefox and IE - it WORKS.
Ubuntu virtual machine with Chrome Stable - not working

Colleague machine, sat next to me, Chrome WORKS. 
We are on the same network.

Can anyone fathom what is wrong here?

Comment: sandicliffe.co.uk always redirects to www.sandicliffe.co.uk . If it's not needed remove first two lines.

Comment: I don't think you understand the issue. We need sandicliffe.co.uk to redirect to www.sandicliffe.co.uk, but it DOESN'T. It just doesn't work. Try visiting just "sandicliffe.co.uk". This is the problem.

Comment: It works for me just now. It's probably a cache issue with your browser ;)

Comment: Hmm. The problem lies in using Chrome Beta !!!